# How to import try_import()?

Tags: python

I am trying to define a variable "pretrainedmodels" as "try_import('efficientnet-pytorch')"
But, I am getting the following error:

```
NameError name 'try_import' is not defined
```

I am not able to figure out how to import it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try_import()` doesn't exist.
if you want to try to import a module use that

```
try:
    import something
except ImportError:
    print("import failed")
```

Answer (score 1):

The commentator above is right, but you can create this module by creating a file in the folder that your program is in called try_import.py (it has to have that name). Here is the `try_import` module:

```
def import_it(module):
  try:
      exec('import ' + module)
  except ImportError: return False # return False because the module was not imported.
  return True # if it goes through
```

Then, to run that module, try `try_import.import_it("module")` where module is the module that you want to import, i.e. `"sys"`, `"os"`, `"pandas"`, etc.